# Validaciones con jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Tengo un inconveniente con una simple validación de rut que realizo con [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). El tema es que cuando jQuery valida algo, arroja un mensaje, en mi caso muestra un globito flotante sobre el campo validado y adicional a esto, coloca el campo en un cuadro rojo (esto con CSS).

El jQuery Validate que tengo es el siguiente, también dejo la función que estoy utilizando para la validación del rut, que se encuentra fuera del `validate`:

```
$(function(){

  $('#form').validate({
    ignore: '[readonly=readonly]',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      var lastError = $(element).data('lastError'), newError = $(error).text();
      $(element).data('lastError', newError);

      if (newError !== '' && newError !== lastError) {
        $(element).popover({
          trigger: "manual",
          placement: "auto top",
          content: newError,
          container: "body",
          template: "<div class=\"popover\" role=\"tooltip\"><div class=\"arrow\"></div><div class=\"popover-content\"><p></p></div></div>"
        });
        if (element.is(':hidden')) {
          $(element).next('span').popover('show').addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
          // console.log('hidden element');
        }else {
          $(element).popover("show").parents(".form-group").addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
          // console.log('normal element');
        }
      }
    },  
    success: function (label, element) {
      $(element).popover("hide").parents(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    },


    rules: {  },
    messages: {  }
  });
  $.validator.addMethod("2_rut", function(value, element){
    return this.optional(element) || $.Rut.validar(value);
  }, "Este campo debe ser un rut valido.");
  $('#2_rut').Rut({
    validation: false
  });
});
```

Lo que sucede es que al hacer `submit` me valida todo OK, pero al intentar validar otro rut, posterior al `submit`, no me arroja el globo con el mensaje, sino que sólo queda el campo envuelto en rojo, como mencionaba antes, (le saqué el código del cuadro rojo en caso que fuera el problema, pero sigue igual).

Y he aquí mi duda, no sé cómo obligar que me muestre el mensaje siempre.

**EDIT**

Se me olvidaba comentar, que los rut que deseo validar y que aparezca el mensaje son dinámicos, es decir, pueden ser varios campos rut que tenga que validar. Normalmente lo hace, pero al hacer un `submit` el mensaje ya no aparece.

**EDIT**

Haciendo pruebas con el código adjunto anteriormente, nos pudimos dar cuenta de que el popover (o globito) aparece para validar los campos dinámicos pero siempre en una única posición, NO sobre el campo que debiera validar. Así que podemos asumir que el problema es, la posición en la que aparece el popover.

Como podríamos especificarle a JQUERY que el popover debe aparecer sobre el campo que estamos validando.

Comment: ¿Podría ser la misma causa/solución que para esta otra pregunta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6119/clonar-una-tabla-completa-sin-clases-y-validar-ambas-tablas?

Comment: Publico esto como respuesta porque aun no puedo comentar. Creo que tu problema es que estas usando muchas veces el mismo id en todos los campos que quieres validar (id='#2_rut'). Verifica esto y si es así cambia el id por clase o usa ids diferentes para cada elemento. Un id debe ser único en todo el DOM.

Comment: Deberias poner algo mas de código que ayudase a resolver esto.De todas formas todo tiene pinta de ser duplicidad de IDs

Comment: Lo suyo e que en vez de por id les pongas un class a los objetos y el selector lo hagas con ".myClass" en vez de por id con # y luego puedes hacer .each(".myClass" para hacer algo sobre todos ellos.

Comment: podrías poner tu código HTML final, solo como ejemplo?

Comment: Y cómo estás declarando el popover? O se declara implícitamente al llamar a jQuery.validate sobre un formulario?

Comment: @x_Mario ya entendí, tu popover está dentro de `errorPlacement`. Podrías probar cambiando el valor de `placement: "auto top"` o derechamente comentando esa línea

Comment: @amenadiel Los comentarios no deberían ser para publicar respuestas. Realmente inhiben a que otros contesten. Creo que deberías publicar lo que comentaste.

Comment: Te recomiendo que utilize el jqueryvalidation engine, aquí te dejo un demo: 
http://me.position-absolute.com/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html

El link de descaga: https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Answer (score 1):

```js
alert($( "input[id^='rut']" ).length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="rut1">
<input type="text" id="rut2">
<input type="text" id="rut3">
<input type="text" id="rut4">
```

El error por el cual no te valida es debido a que no estas variando el ID del input (los id deben ser unicos para que el DOM no haga referencias erroneas). Es por eso que jquery no puede validar la referencia exacta en el DOM para evitar eso puedes agregarle un número al id del input:

`<input id="rut1" type="" ...>
<input id="rut2" type="" ...>
....`

No especificas que estas usando del lado del servidor, aunque la creación del input y su id incrementable la puedes hacer con javascript puro y duro o jquery.

Una vez hagas esto de los inputs seleccionas con jquery todos los valores de input que tengan el id rut (se evalua solo la palabra que contiene el id, para poder saber cuantos existen):

`$( "input[id^='rut']" ).length`

Esto te devuelve la cantidad de inputs que tienen esa palabra por ejemplo 3

Así sabemos cuantos inputs con datos de rut tenemos y ya solo es validar cada uno de estos con tu función de validar.